# Error while creating Elasticsearch API Client(8.0.1) object using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am implementing Elasticsearch 8.0.1 version using Spring Boot. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/8.0/installation.html), this is the `pom.xml` of my project

```
<project>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

This is the Configuration class (`ElasticsearchConfiguration.java`)

```
    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchClient client() {
        RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9900)).build();

        // Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
        ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(
                restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

        // And create the API client
        ElasticsearchClient client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);

        return client;
    }
}
```

And the main class includes the following part of the code

```
    @Bean
    public boolean createTestIndex() throws Exception {
        CreateIndexResponse createResponse = elasticsearchClient.indices().create(
                new CreateIndexRequest.Builder()
                        .index("my-index")
                        .aliases("foo",
                                new Alias.Builder().isWriteIndex(true).build()
                        )
                        .build()
        );
        return true;
    }

}
```

But when I run the project I am getting below error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'soSearchApp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'elasticsearchClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'client' defined in class path resource [com/esexperts/config/ElasticsearchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient]: Factory method 'client' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/json/spi/JsonProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at com.esexperts.soSearchApp.main(soSearchApp.java:29) ~[classes/:an]
```

**Can anyone please help me resolve this issue ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by adding a dependency `jakarta.json:jakarta.json-api:2.0.1`  mentioned in this [Discuss post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/error-while-creating-elasticsearch-api-client-8-0-1-object-using-spring-boot/300263/2?u=bhavya)

Comment: Glad you figured out, but still Spring Boot doesn't support ES 8 as of March 24th and even if this dependency solves this issue, it doesn't mean everything else will work

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot [doesn't yet support ES 8](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#preface.versions).

Also [worth reading this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/2108#issuecomment-1067466807).

So a safer alternative for now is to use ES 7.17.1

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/json/spi/JsonProvider`